# SuperUser not working properly in CyanogenMod 11

Tags: android, su

I made an Android app that internally calls `su -c "pm ..."`. However, I get **Permission denied** when my app tries to execute this.

My app appears as `Deny` in the SuperUser log section, but CYM does not ask me via a Toast what I want to do, nor it appears in the `Allow/Deny` list...

Clues?

Thanks!

L.

Comment: You might not have specified the [ACCESS_SUPERUSER permission](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/T9xnMJEnzf1) in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @Vinayak: True, but I didn't set "Declared Permission" in Superuser section.

Comment: @Vinayak: Nothing happens, but I forced my app through SuperSu instead of CYM built in superuser. It works now, but my app still does not shows in the CYM superuser allow list.

Comment: It won't show there if SuperSU has bypassed it. Removing SuperSU might achieve that.

Comment: I already removed it, still not showing. Very strange. I should try another root app to see if it appears, not sure which.

Comment: @Vinayak: I upgraded to CYM 11 M10, so I lost the SuperSU permissions on my APP (I removed SuperSU before the upgrade). And the problem persist: CYM does not ask me for SuperUser permission for my app, it just denies it, and my app appears as `Deny` in the settings. And now my app does have ACCESS_SUPERUSER permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to CYM 11 M10, and now su works fine. No doubt it was a bug. So now I can mount/umount encrypted stuff as I was always able to do.

It seems the problem is solved in the M10 build.